# Allow any parameters for a route

Tags: angular

Is it possible in Angular 6 to have a route that can take any parameters. I have following call back from an auth provider, and the route fails:

```
http://localhost:4200/authcallback#id_token=xx&session_state=e59daa61-7342-425a-b484-0c36440be471
```

I have following route:

```
{path:'authcallback', component: AuthCallbackComponent},  

const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
};
```

Maybe one day the provider provides more parameters so would be nice if I can get the above, and if any other params then just ignore them.

Comment: Do you import your routing module correctly ?

Comment: do you want like this localhost:4200/authcallback/anything?

Comment: Shouldn't `#` be `?`?

Comment: With the `#` they are not parameters, just anchors. You may have something without the `#` but with the `?` instead, are you?

Comment: I am not sure ahy azure AD adds this, I am going to follow up on that.

Comment: I cant be Azure AD, must be something Angular adds in the routing?